# why is awk not writing variable to csv file?

Tags: awk

I have a csv file that I need to add a number of columns at the end. The new columns are variables taken from other files.

```
STNO=3389
STNNAME=SWORDS

awk -F "," '{ stnname='"$STNNAME"';stno='"$STNO"';print $0","stnname","stno }' infile
```

example of the output.

992501062,-6.278983000,202105210736,,3389

The stno is written fine but the stnname is blank. It seems like I can use numeric variables but not text.

any help appreciated.
thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, sorry but this is not clear, could you please explain it more what you are trying to achieve here, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 apologies I wasn't clear enough, I'm newish to this and was trying to be as concise as possible. Tks for the reply

Comment: I suspect there's a better approach that involves just running awk on your CSV and the files you''re populating those variables from rather  than extracting their values in shell first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interpolating the literal symbol `SWORDS` where apparently you were hoping to interpolate a quoted string.  Awk has no variable named `SWORDS` so it resolves to an empty string.

Better hygiene and stability altogether is to avoid interpolating junk right into your Awk script.  Use `-v` on the Awk command line to pass in values.

```sh
awk -v stnname="$STNNAME" -v stno="$STNO" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
{ print $0, stnname , stno }' infile
```

Tangentially, [avoid upper case for your private shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to get lost in a sea of quotes. Maybe catch the env variables using `-v` like this:

```
awk -v stnname="$STNNAME" -v stno="$STNO" -F "," '{ print $0,stnname,stno }' infile
```

then you can use them in the command directly without trying to piece together a string

Comment: You need to set `OFS` to a comma too.

Comment: True - I focused on the `-v` bit... your answer has the whole thing